# Is it obligatory to participate in conference if accepted?

Tags: conference, paper-submission

I submitted my article to a Scopus-indexed conference. A month later, they informed me that my paper was accepted and that all that was left to do was paying registration fees and present the paper in order to get it published. However, when I discussed this with my supervisor, he told me that I should have looked for Thomson-indexed journals/conferences.

Can I cancel this? Are there any consequences if I do?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure your supervisor wants you to withdraw? He might just have been annoyed, but not want you to do anything about it. His name is (probably) on the paper, and he might not want to displease the conference organizers. Try to remember the conversation as carefully as you can and don't do anything unless you are sure! Clarify with the supervisor if needed!

Comment: The previous comment is spot-on, but why be so cautious about asking your adviser? Send them an email to confirm if you should withdraw it or not. There's nothing wrong with this, specially since the original problem was caused by a lack of communication.

Comment: Is the conference in-person or online? Almost everything is online in my field at the moment, mostly at little or no cost.  If it's online and the fees are still high, I'd want to look into how well respected the conference is, especially as it's not indexed.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As long as you haven't signed over any copyrights the paper is still yours. Yes, you can withdraw it. The organizers will grumble a bit, but you can ignore that. And even if you have already signed rights away you can ask to have them returned, which might happen or not.

But don't make a habit of this. The reviewers spent some effort on your paper that is now wasted.

The only other consequence is that your paper gets delayed. That could be a problem or not, depending on how many others are working in closely related areas.

Answer (score 11):

To be honest, this is not the nicest thing to do to conference organizers. Assume your paper is very strong and the organizers look forward to have that in their conference and you now you pulling it out will disappoint them (apart from the reviewer time being wasted).

Now, if you have to make the choice between your supervisor and the conference organizers, your supervisor takes precedence. But in the future, you should check that ahead of time.

Generally, it is not good form to submit and then to pull out without good reason. Legally, you can do so, as long as the copyright is not signed over.

Comment: Also, it is OK to have freedom and being independent researcher asap. Still, if one has a supervisor, it means s/he has a supervisor. To say that one should not submit anything without the supervisor at least knowing.